# Typescript React accept only one html element for children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make `children` to support only one type of jsx element. For example, I have the following structure

```
<Test>
  <img src="..." />
  <div>Testing</div>
</Test>
```

I would like to check the `children` and make sure the `img` comes first and then `any` element, meaning that if I don't start with `img` or I swap the element, it should give me a type checking error.

I've tried creating an interface like:

```
interface ITest {
  children: [
    React.DetailedHTMLProps<
      React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>,
      HTMLImageElement
    >,
    React.ReactElement<HTMLDivElement>
  ];
}
```

but I'm not getting any type checking error, it accepts `<img><div>`, `<div><img>` and any other component `<Something><img>`

Any idea?

Comment: did you got that piece of code working